# Validating a textfield value using nodeJs

Tags: node.js

How can I `validate` a field and confirm the field is not empty in `Node.js`

The code I used is as follows. Even I send an empty field the error message doesn't get displayed.

```
if (req.body.password !=="") {
     res.render('user/s_in',{csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),messages: 'Field is empty'});

    return;
}
```

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.password));` to see what's actually there. Perhaps it's `null` instead of `""`?

Comment: I think its your if statement, ("" !== "") will return false, it will return true if its undefined or null

Answer (score 0):

Did you use body-parser middleware before your validate api?

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/your/validate/api', function(req, res){
  if (req.body.password !=="") {
     res.render('user/s_in',{csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),messages: 'Field is empty'});

     return;
   }
});
```